# Can pandas.concat handle non float64 dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataset so I have compressed data as best I can by converting dtypes to smallest possible type and using `Series.to_sparse` on some columns (achieving around 80% compression).  However, when I try to concatenate 2 of these datasets (both with same compression and dtypes) I lose this compression. I.e.:

```
dfmerged = pd.concat((df1, df2), 0)
```

`dfmerged.dtypes` is now all `float64`. I tried doing the following:

```
for c in df1.columns:
  if dfmerged[c].dtype != df1[c].dtype: 
      dfmerged[c] = dfmerged[c].astype(df1[c].dtype)
```

However this gives me an Error: 'Can only support floating point data for now'.

Original column can be `uint8`, `uint16`, etc. So I guess `float64.astype(uint8)` is not supported?

What is the best way I can achieve this?  Will I need to create the DataFrame from scratch by creating individual Series with correct type information?

Pandas Version: 0.15.0-6-g403f38d

Python: 2.7

Comment: sparse is not fully supportive ATM, as needing someone to develop and extend its capabilities. A dense frame however IS fully supportive of all dtypes. If you have lots of data you should use a disk-based format and chunk, e.g. HDFStore (or bcolz)

Comment: Welcome contributions for Sparse enhancements!

Comment: I downloaded pd source a while back and I peed myself a little (problem with having highly performant code I guess). Maybe I'll give it another shot one of these days :)